# SqlPackage /Profile properties

Tags: sql-server, sqlpackage

Where I can find SqlPackage XML profile documentation?

Let me explain: on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver15#properties-specific-to-the-publish-action) you can find documentation about all switches you can pass to SqlPackage directly on the command line.

The documentation says that you can use also an XML profile BUT does not mention **in any way** what are the equivalent switches for the XML profile, for example for the switch `CreateNewDatabase` the equivalent is the same `<CreateNewDatabase>False</CreateNewDatabase>` **BUT** for example `ExcludeObjectType=Users`, you must use `<ExcludeUsers>True</ExcludeUsers>`.

It seems that all boolean switches can be used inside the XML profile, but I'm now sure.

I did not find any documentation/XSD schema about this *mapping* between the cli switch and related XML properties.

Searching on Google I found that someone uses Visual Studio to generate the publish profile, but I'm using the Azure Data Studio project with an SDK-style project (preview) and when I open the project inside Visual Studio it tries to upgrade the project to .NET Framework 4.8.

Inside Azure Data Studio on the Database project, I can only create a basic publish profile.

Comment: If it were me and it was important to use ADS instead of VS for ongoing development, I'd create a test project in VS (Community Edition is free of charge) and create a publish profile wherein you toggle the setting that you care about and see how it affects the XML. Of course, you then need to ensure that a profile that incorporates those properties is compatible with the ADS version of database projects.

Comment: @BenThul Thanks for the suggestions, unfortunately, the visual studio XML settings are incompatible with the SDK-style project.

Comment: @Max `visual studio XML settings` I'm sure Ben meant publish.xml settings, not sqlproj contents. publish.xml is the same, in SSDT it has separate GUI dialog with checkboxes. And if I'm not mistaken there is no complete docs neither on sqlproj contents nor publish.xml. If you need to enable/disable some specific options, please update your question and me or someone else will be able to give you example of correct publish.xml

Answer (score 0):

the XML values are Properties names, [here is the full list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.tools.schema.tasks.sql.sqlpublishtask.additionaldeploymentcontributorarguments?view=sql-dacfx-162) scroll on the left panel.